# My app can't connect to another app service if service was installed after client app

Tags: java, android, android-service

my app connects to another app service and transfer some data. i configure permissions in manifest file and everything works fine. but i i have a big problem. my app works and connect properly to that service if only installed after that service! if i first install my app and then install that service, i doesn't work and i get this error:

> Not allowed to bind to service Intent

even i restart my phone it doesn't effect! what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known (by design/won't fix) issue with custom permissions - you cannot use a custom permission if it is not known to the system at the time when your app is installed.

Since the custom permission is defined in the manifest of the service apk which hasn't yet been installed, the system doesn't know about it when setting up the actual permissions of your client app, so it is effectively filtered out.

You will need to either get your users to install the service apk before the client, or else use some other scheme than a custom permission.  For example, you might be able to do something by allowing any app to talk to you, but only responding to those with a key of some sort (though keys can be extracted by reverse engineering...)